# What kind of file path starts with "\\.\"?

Tags: windows, tls, avast

I use Avast Web Shield, and it intercepts TLS traffic from the browser using the env variable:

`SSLKEYLOGFILE  \\.\aswMonFltProxy\FFFFDE812B3DD840`

While I don't actually mind that it does this, and I understand why it does so, I got curious as to what this "path" actually points to. My first thought is this is either some kind of Netbios address or a socket connection, but I really have no idea.

Does anyone have any idea what this kind of "path" is and if it's actually mappable to a physical file on the disk or maybe in memory?

Comment: its a mountpoint, not sure to what though... You can use the following to get an example of another mountpoint: `dir \\.\c:\` to get a listing of c:\. This allows you to create, access and delete filenames that normally are impossible, such as prn, con, lpt, etc. They are network mappings to a local point on the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\\.` prefix is used for accessing the ["device namespace"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file), which works somewhat like Linux /dev or even /sys. (It corresponds to the subfolder `\GLOBAL??` in the NT object namespace, so you can browse its contents using WinObjEx.)

From what I know, Windows resolves object paths incrementally, providing an effect similar to mountpoints, so `\\.\aswMonFltProxy` will likely be a device object created by Avast's filtering driver, and the remainder is handled by that driver itself – most likely returning a "pipe" object or similar. Firefox can write data to one end of the pipe and the driver receives.

(Windows also has actual named pipes, which live under the `\\.\Pipe` prefix and work in a very similar way – when accessing e.g. `\\.\Pipe\whatever`, the first part gets resolved to the named-pipe device driver, the remainder to the actual namedpipefs object.)

Generally, none of those objects are physical – they only exist in the kernel's memory. Only some objects (e.g. `\\.\C:`) correspond to a physical disk and allow reaching back into the "real" filesystem.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and the tip for the WinObjEx program.